# Syntax error: "done" unexpected (expecting "do")

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ]
do
java -server -Xmx4G -XX:MaxPermSize=4096M -jar bin.jar
sleep 2
done
```

Comment: use () instead of []

Comment: Can you make this script foer me

Answer (score 0):

`[ ... ]` is an alternative spelling for `test`, e.g. both

```
[ "$1" = "abc" ]
test "$1" = "abc"
```

mean exactly the same thing.

The result of such a test is either true, which means the test returns 0 (zero), as zero means *success* in terms of shell commands. Or it is anything else, which means false as all other values mean *failure* in terms of shell commands.

`true` is not constant in shell scripting, `true` is a binary (`/bin/true`), which may also be a built-in in some shells and it simply always returns zero, so it is always successful. Just like `false` (`/bin/false`) always returns one, so it is never successful.

A test like

```
if [ true ]
```

makes no sense, as what are you testing here? It is equal to

```
if test true
then
```

and `test` (which is `/bin/test` by the way and `[` is `/bin/[` and a symlink to it; but typically it is a shell built-in for speed) has no idea what you mean by "true". If you just want to call `/bin/true` to get a zero result code, you would write

```
if true
then
```

which calls `true` and then checks the result code being zero.

And the same goes for `while`, which will continue to loop as long as the expression following it evaluates to zero, so it must be

```
while true
do
```

And as you seem new to shell scripting, a built-in means that the shell recognizes one of the standard shell commands and has an own implementation of it, so instead of calling the real command, which is slow as a new process must be started first, it just calls its internal implementation that will behave alike. Pretty much any command can be a built-in and many basic commands like `test`(`[`), `true`, and `false` are pretty much always built-in's, yet they don't have to, that's why you will still find real binaries for them in `/bin`.

Comment: You will write for me because I am handicapped

Comment: @MateuszGrabowski I did already write it for you in my answer. There is only one line you need to replace and I showed you which line you need to replace and explained why you need to replace it. All you need to do is copy&paste it. If you cannot copy&paste, then it's pointless that I write anything for you as you couldn't copy&paste that either.